# How to query data from two tables using django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have mySQL tables connected with "one to many" relationship

params of the main table are:

- name
- age
- height

params of the second table are:

- f_name (as foreign key of first table)
- salary_date
- salary

So I need to do something like:

```sql
select * from table2
where t_id in( select t_id from table1
   where t_var = 'Alfred'
);
```

I already get data from first table using this code:

### models.py

```py
from tabnanny import verbose
from django.db import models, connections
from django.urls import reverse


class collection_data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age =models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Collection Data'



class second_data(models.Model):
    # connect this table with previos
    data = models.ForeignKey(collection_data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    salary= models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    salary_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Frequent Collection Data'
        ordering = ['salary_date']
```

### views.py

```py
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class InfoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = collection_data
    template_name = 'info/Info.html'
    context_object_name = 'info'
```

### urls.py

```py
path('<int:pk>', views.InfoDetailView.as_view(), name="info-data"),
```

### Info.html

```html
<ul class="data">
  <li>{{ info.name }}</li>
  <li>{{ info.age }}</li>
  <li>{{ info.height}}</li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
{% for el in second_data %}
  <tr>
    <td>05/06/2021</td>
    <td>1350$</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Result on the page must be:
[image]

Comment: what data you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve data from second_data table like if I use sql statement

select * from table2 where 
id in (select f_id from table1
where name = "Alfred")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all `second_data` objects related to `collection_data` in template, you need to use `{% for el in info.second_data_set.all %}` instead of `{% for el in second_data %}`. Consider setting `related_name` attribute of `models.ForeignKey()` so you can do something like `{% for el in info.'related_name'.all %}`.

Also try using CamelCase for class names (`CollectionData` instead of `collected_data`).

Comment: Thank you dude, that's relly helps, I wish you great success in programming 

Answer (score 1):

```
query = second_data.objects.all()
```

then in your html file like just write like this way

```
{% for item in query %}
         {{ item.salary }}
         {{ item.salary_date }}
{{ endfor }}
```